# How to add dependency jar files during compiling stage using gradle?

Tags: java, android, gradle

I build my `Android` application using `Gradle`.

The dependency jar files are retrieved during compiling stage and the path of these jar files are dynamic (because there is build number in the path, for example, **/home/user1/workspace/myapp/libs/privatejar/build-1019/a.jar**).

My gradle configue file looks like this.

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.javaCompile.dependsOn('GetJarUsingCompanyPrivateProtocol')
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('local/path/of/company/private/jar')
}

task GetJarUsingCompanyPrivateProtocol {
    // This command will retrieve the jar
    // into folder "local/path/of/company/private/jar"
    commandLine 'get_jar_command'
}
```

Because the jar files do not exist before executing gradle compile command for the 1st time, it will always complain "Class * can not be found".
However, if I execute gradle compile for the 2nd time, it will work.

So I have two questions here:

1. I have to change the **local/path/of/company/private/jar** every time when there is change to the build number of my jar files
2. Is there any chance to make my gradle script work for the 1st time?

I know I can execute **get_jar_command** and then trigger `gradle` build, but it is annoying, can I achieve it in one shot?

Comment: Seems like local maven repository is what you need.

Comment: @av_lee Thanks, local maven is a choice. But I don't want to setup a maven repository only for such a 'small' case. Is there any other choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found solution by myself.

Gradle build has three distinct phases:

1. Initialization
2. Configuration
3. Execution

The **dependencies** block will be executed during the configuration phase. So to use dependency jar in **dependencies** block, dependency jar must be download, either in initialization phase, or in configuration phase but before **dependencies** block execution.

In my case, initialization phase is not used. So I must ensure the dependency jar be downloaded before **dependencies** block. It's simply, adjusting the block sequence will be OK.

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.javaCompile.dependsOn('GetJarUsingCompanyPrivateProtocol')
    }
}

task GetJarUsingCompanyPrivateProtocol {
    // This command will retrieve the jar
    // into folder "local/path/of/company/private/jar"
    commandLine 'get_jar_command'
}

dependencies {
    compile files('local/path/of/company/private/jar')
}
```

Note: logic in doLast of task will be executed in execution phase. That's why I use

```
task GetJarUsingCompanyPrivateProtocol {
    commandLine 'get_jar_command'
}
```

Neither

```
task GetJarUsingCompanyPrivateProtocol {
    doLast {
        commandLine 'get_jar_command'
    }
}
```

nor

```
task GetJarUsingCompanyPrivateProtocol << {
    commandLine 'get_jar_command'
}
```